# Как исправить баг с регулярным выражением?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, winforms

Сделал регулярное выражение на ввод только буквенных символов, но чисто случайно отловил баг с тем, что если к концу строки дописать цифру, то выражение все равно будет `true`.

Как можно поправить эту регулярку, чтобы при вводе цифры в строке выражение вернуло `false`

```
  private void nameBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((IsNameValid = (new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]")).IsMatch(nameBox.Text)) && IsPhoneValid && IsStreetValid && IsTownValid && IsPasswordValid && IsSurnameValid && IsEmailValid && IsPasswordEqual == true)
        {
            registrationButton.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            registrationButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        if(IsNameValid == true)
        {
            nameTip.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            nameTip.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Убрать `^`.....

Comment: А зачем вам вообще тут регулярка? Написали `.All(char.IsLetter)` и все.

Comment: @Bulson наоборот же - добавить `$`, чтобы требовалась **вся** строка из букв

Comment: @Евгений я не силен в регулярках, но крышка же говорит о начале строки? Если ее убрать, тогда будет вся строка, зачем еще `$`? Доллар говорит о конце строки.

Comment: @Buls С убранной крышкой и со знаком доллара в конце выражение возвращает false

Comment: @Bulson если убрать крышку и не добавить доллар, выражение будет проверять, есть ли в тексте буквы, а не состоит ли оно из них

Comment: так же без крышки и доллара возвращает true если в строку ввести допусти John6, что для имени не подходит

Comment: @Евгений , спасибо, понял.

Comment: @Bulson ответ отметил, все оказалось куда ещё интереснее, что никогда в регулярках не встречал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно проверить, состоит ли строка **только** из букв, вам нужно проверять всю строку, а не только её начало

Ваша регулярка: выражение начинается с буквы

```
^[a-zA-Z]
```

Регулярка: выражение начинается с множества букв

```
^[a-zA-Z]+
```

Уже ближе, но всё ещё не то.

Регулярка: выражение состоит только из букв (минимум 1 буква)

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Символ `$` указывает на то, что после букв строка должна закончиться. Т.е. между началом и концом строки должны быть только буквы